# User provided array name in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So i am fetching rows from my database using AJAX and then turning them into an array with a variable identifier Here is the code
 PHP:

```
 $query_val = $_GET["val"];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eventos_main WHERE nome_evento LIKE '%$query_val%' OR local_evento LIKE '%$query_val%' OR descricao_evento LIKE '%$query_val%'");
  for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($result);$i++){
    $array = array();
    $array[$query_val] = mysql_fetch_row($result);       //fetch result 
    echo json_encode($array);
  }
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$('#s_query').keyup(function(){
        var nome = document.getElementById('s_query').value;
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'search.php',        
            data: '&val='+nome,
            dataType: 'json',     
            success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(nome);
            var image_loc = data.nome[7];
            console.log(image_loc);
```

If i change the line `var image_loc = data.nome[7];` to `var image_loc = data.nidst[7];` it works perfectly. Nidst is the term i search for.
This code returns the error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '7' of undefined".
What should i do?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Yes i saw it on the php website, but i'll update my code later when i have everything done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
var image_loc = data[nome][7];
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? it's the correct answer.(for the javascript side of the problem atleast, this doesn't address the invalid json being returned when there are more than 1 records)

Comment: This is obviously one of the problems, not sure why it was downvoted? +1 .

Comment: I didn't downvote, but wouldn't it actually be helpful if this was explained? Some people, unfortunately, may not understand why `data.nome` wouldn't work compared to `data[nome]`.

Comment: It's true, I didn't address the possibly invalid JSON, because this wasn't the issue here(`data.nidst[7]` returns a result, so `data` must be valid JSON) . But of course the JSON-issue has to be fixed too.

Comment: I'm not seeing a downvote here. 1 upvote, 0 downvotes. I haven't even started drinking yet... lol

Answer (score 3):

`data.nome[7];` is trying to access a property of `data` named `nome`, which doesn't exist. Since you declared a variable `nome` which holds your desired property name, you need to reference the **value** as the property name, like `data[nome][7]`.

Example: If `var nome = 'foo'`, then `data[nome][7]` will evaluate to `data['foo'][7]` which is the same as `data.foo[7]`.

What you are doing is `data.nome[7]` which is the same as `data['nome'][7]`, and the only way that would work is if `var nome = 'nome'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that server does not resond with valid json data. Try to modify the code:

```
$array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $array[$query_val] = mysql_fetch_row($result);
}
die(json_encode($array));
```